# Default appearance of static grouped UITableView with multiple sections

Tags: uitableview, static, sections, grouped-table

Did Apple change default appearance of grouped cells in table ?

I defined static grouped UITableView with multiple sections in Storyboard, expected the cells to appear as in this tutorial:

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-static-table-view-storyboard/

However it looks like that:

[image: static uitableview]

Is there a way to change the appearance in storyboard (**not** programmatically), to show the grouped cells inside rounded corner boxes as in the tutorial ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your phone, the "Settings" app uses a grouped type of table view.
Yes, since iOS7 (when iOS got redesigned) the shape of the grouped table view changed.

You're looking at an old tutorial with old screenshots.

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought, I checked the "Settings" already as you suggested and saw it looks the same, just wanted to verify I didn't miss anything. Thanks.